# dispatch `c()` on two arguments

Tags: r, methods

I would like to set methods for concatenating an S3 class in R for which method dispatch does not depend on the order of the arguments.  The usual S3 dispatch methods are not symmetric:

```
x = 3
class(x) = 'foo'
y = 4
c.foo <- function(...)sum(...)
c(x,y)
#> [1] 7
c(y,x)
#> [1] 4 3
```

and the S4 method for `c()` does not dispatch on the `...` argument.  I'm familiar with `rbind2` and `cbind2` methods from the the 'methods' package, but I can't seem to find an equivalent for concatenation.

Comment: S4 methods _do_ dispatch on '...' as described on `?dotsMethods`, although I think the generic for "c" has been given a first argument 'x'. I don't think this helps with your problem.

Comment: You're exactly right.  I clarified my comment about the S4 method dispatch...

Comment: I think you are out of luck. You are basically asking for a different language.

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust.  That's what I thought.  I was just hoping I had missed something from the 'mehods' package or elsewhere.